# Marketing Cloud Page not updating Salescloud record

Tags: marketing-cloud, salesforce1-app, cloudpage

I have a cloud page in marketing cloud this i need to update a salescloud record when they click through to the page via a button.

Its not currently doing that even though to me the code looks right. Can anyone help?

````
%%[

Set @subscriberkey = RequestParameter("_subscriberkey")
SET @email = RequestParameter("emailaddr")

  set @sub = CreateObject("Subscriber")
  SetObjectProperty(@sub, "EmailAddress", @email)
  SetObjectProperty(@sub, "SubscriberKey", @subscriberkey)
  SetObjectProperty(@sub, "Status", "Active")
  
  set @updateOptions = CreateObject("UpdateOptions")
  set @saveOptions = CreateObject("SaveOption")
  SetObjectProperty(@saveOptions,"SaveAction","UpdateAdd")
  SetObjectProperty(@saveOptions,"PropertyName","*")
  AddObjectArrayItem(@updateOptions,"SaveOptions", @saveOptions)
  
  set @updateRecord = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject('Lead',_subscriberkey,'Referral_Opt_In__c','True')

  set @statusCode = InvokeUpdate(@sub, @updateStatusMessage, @updateErrorCode, @updateOptions)

]%%


<style>
body,html{
  background-color:white;
  }
 
 p{
 color: #000;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.50em;
    margin: 0 0 15px;
 font-family: 'Gotham B','Gotham A',Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
  text-align:center;

 }
 
 @media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  
  p{
   color: #000;
   font-family: 'Gotham B','Gotham A',Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
   font-size: 20px;
   font-style: normal;
   text-align:center;

  }
 
  
 }
 .logo-block{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    max-width: 60rem;
 padding-top:5rem;
    padding-bottom: 5rem;
 text-align:center;
    
}
 .logo{
 margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 15rem;
}


</style>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="logo-block">
  <img alt="Logo" class="logo" src="https://image.info.healthcoachinstitute.com/lib/fe3f157175640478751372/m/2/f42a7452-8de9-4b31-984c-8495922d7b44.png">
 </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
   
    <div class="col-sm-6">
  <p>Congratulations, you've opted in!</p>
  
   </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
  </div>
</div>```
````

Comment: May I ask, what do you mean by "when they to it"?

Comment: Oops I mean when then click through to the cloud page via marketing cloud it should update their record.

Comment: Could you please correct this in your question? You can edit it.

Comment: I would suggest you segment this ampscript out and also test that needed parameters are what you expect like printing _subscriberkey